# Bash script to control grunt build

Tags: linux, bash, cron, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am more sysadmin that developer so maybe there is a way and i don't know how.
Im triying to (i am commanded to) deploy some cronjobs to run a nightly grunt build. 
The problem is i don't know how i can extract from the build that the build has been successful or a failure.

Of course i can use perl regex and capture the screen but i don't know, maybe there is a better way to do that, isn't?

On the documentation of Grunt there is no thing related with that, is more "how works grunt" that "how i can interact with grunt".

Using linux Centos & debian.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the man page, near thr end of this exit code will be $? expands to this. You can also use || and && to distinguish between success and any failure

Comment: Are you sure Grunt has a man page?

Comment: It may not,but all *nix have exit code '

Comment: Sorry accidental early post... code 0 success and non zero 1 or more failure. Try if [ $? -e 0 ]; then ; echo good ; else ; echo bad ; fi this must be the next statement after grunt, even calls to functions may butcher $?.

Comment: Sorry typo, in the square brackets, that -e should be -eq